# Node.jsのファイルをSingle Executable Applicationsで実行ファイルに変換する際自作モジュールがimportできません

Tags: node.js

Linux(Ubuntu20.04)×Node.jsで実験中です。
https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html
に書かれてある手順通り行い、実行ファイル(hello)を作り、無事動きました。
JSファイルを２つに分けたいと思っているので、次のように改変してみました。

★hello.js

```
console.log(`Hello, ${process.argv[2]}!`);
```

を

```
import { formatDate } from './basic.js';
console.log(formatDate());
```

に変更。

★basic.jsを同じフォルダ内に追加作成

```
export function formatDate() {
  let d = new Date();
  return d.getFullYear() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate();
}
```

importを使って関数を呼び出せるようにするため、package.jsonに次を追加

```
"type": "module"
```

まず通常のNode.jsの実行を行います

```
$ node hello.js
```

結果は

```
2024/2/29
```

で成功

次に上述の
https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html
の手順に従いコンパイルして実行ファイルhelloが生成されるところまでは行ったのですが、
それを実行するとエラーになり、次のようなメッセージが出ます。

```
$ ./hello
(node:61855) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `hello --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
hello.js:1
import { formatDate } from './basic.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at embedderRunCjs (node:internal/util/embedding:19:27)
    at node:internal/main/embedding:18:8

Node.js v20.11.1
```

Warningの部分で'set "type": "module" in the package.json'とありますが、
上記の通りpackage.jsonにset済みです。

一体どこがおかしくてどうすればメインファイルに別のファイルをインポート
できるようになるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コメントがつかないので別のサイトで聞いてみます。よってこのスレは終了させていただきます。では。